# In Three.js (A-Frame) how do I prevent audio clipping?

Tags: three.js, aframe, web-audio-api, game-development

I'm using Mozilla Hubs/Spoke which uses A-Frame which uses Three.js which uses the Web Audio API.

This got me wondering about a theoretical question. When playing multiple audio files at the same time what's the best practice to ensure audio doesn't clip? Technically you could be in a situation where you're unsure how many sound effects play at the same time especially in my case where I'm using them for ambiance and potentially user actions trigger more. I know the Web Audio API provides a [Dynamic Compressor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DynamicsCompressorNode) but none of these technologies appear to use it.

I exported two files at 0dB and played both at the same time and confirmed there appears to be digital distortion due to the two files together being over 0dB.

I'm currently exporting sound effects that I want to add to a scene and wondering at what dB my peaks should sit at? But also wondering if I've missed something and these technologies do implement a compressor/limiter to help with this?

Answer (score 1):

The range of values supported the Web Audio API is actually the range of values that can be represented by a float32 in JavaScript. However the range of "meaningful" values only goes from -1 to +1. But there is nothing which prevents larger numbers from being used.

If your signal exceeds -1 or +1 it depends on the browser and the OS how they handle it. I don't know this for sure but my suspicion is that Chrome caps the signal at -1/+1 before it sends the data to the OS whereas Firefox passes it on without modifying it. macOS seems to have a built-in limiter which kicks in if the signal exceeds -1/+1. This will help with the audio coming from Firefox but it can't help with the audio coming from Chrome since it is already capped.

I think it's a good idea to add a limiter to your audio graph to not rely on the unspecified behavior of the browser and the OS. This is a good article which describes how such a limiter could be build: https://webaudiotech.com/2016/01/21/should-your-web-audio-app-have-a-limiter

The article is using the now deprecated `ScriptProcessorNode` to implement the limiter which is why I created an `AudioWorklet` version of the same algorithm: https://github.com/chrisguttandin/limiter-audio-worklet

Comment: Thanks a heap for this, that summarises things nicely.